# SOAP V2 not adding products to cart

Tags: cart, api, soap

I am adding a product to cart via SOAP V2 API:

```
$client = new SoapClient('http://mywebsite.com/api/v2_soap/?wsdl');
$session = $client->login('username', 'password');

$quoteId = $client->shoppingCartCreate($session);

$customerData = array(
    "firstname" => "Klevis",
    "lastname" => "Miho",
    "email" => "kmiho@myemail.com",
    "customer_id" => 2522,
    "mode" => "customer",
    "website_id" => "1"
);


$resultCustomerSet = $client->shoppingCartCustomerSet($session, $quoteId, $customerData);

$result = $client->shoppingCartProductAdd($session, $quoteId, array(array(
    'product_id' => '336',
    'sku' => '110757',
    'qty' => '1',
    'options' => null,
    'bundle_option' => null,
    'bundle_option_qty' => null,
    'links' => null
)));   

$result1 = $client->shoppingCartInfo($session, $quoteId); 

var_dump($result); //returns true
```

In the end it returns true. But when I login on the frontend there are no products in my shopping cart.

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 2):

The Magento SOAP API is a **web-Service** and is meant for **data exchange** with external systems such as ERP, accounting, etc.
You can create orders via SOAP-API in your shop which you will see afterwards in the customers account as well as in the shop admin-interface.

The use-case you are trying to create is, to fill a customers shopping cart with products.
So, basically, what you're doing is right, it's just not the way the **intended usage** of the web-service.

I've never set it up like this, but what you need to do to achieve your goal is, to create a connection between your visitors/customers session in the browser and the shopping cart.

Depending on your intended usage you'll need to access the visitors', customers' and checkout session:

Get the visitor session:

```
$session = Mage::getSingleton('core/session');
```

Get the customer session:

```
$session = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session');
```

Get the checkout session:

```
$session = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session');
```

Set customers session to checkout session:

```
Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')
    ->setCustomer(Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer());
```

Whatever you do: Be careful with setting, storing,... the session-id via URL and cookies.
This *can* be a potentical security issue.

Comment: Someone is building a android app which just adds products on the cart, then the user can checkout from a desktop. I am testing the SOAP API for that. Makes sense? What do I need to add to make code to make it work?

Comment: I see. Persistant Shopping might also be a solution for you then?!
http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/setting-up-a-persistent-shopping-cart

Comment: I have enabled Persistent Shopping cart, but doesn't solve the problem. Thanks Anna for trying to help me.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to set quote(shopping cart) active by custom code:

```
$quoteData = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->load($quoteId);
if($quoteData->getIsActive()==0) {
  $quoteData->setIsActive(1)->save();
}
```

because by default quote is not activated when its created.